# "Folder" structure of Postgres database missing in DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I guess I did a faulty database restoration or the dump did not have this data and the "folder like" structure was lost. This is a capture of Dbeaver showing what I mean with "foler like" structure. I can easily access the functions, tables, schemas, etc. stored in the database definition. I'm not so worried about the loss of the original structure as it did not have much, but I do want to recreate it step by step when I need it. For example, now I made a function and would like to see it under a "Functions" folder, how can I do that?

Also, what should I have included in the pg_dump generation script to also backup this structure?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't DBeaver always show functions inside the "Functions" folder? Is the function missing, or shown somewhere else?

Comment: The "folder" structure is non existent. Only shows the schemas and tables barebones, not even a "tables" folder. Perhaps is a Dbeaver issue, will check in their forums just in case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the database navigator on the left, right-click on your database connection, and select "Advanced" rather than "Simple":
[image: DBeaver menu to see the "folder structure"]